# How do I create a checkbox on Ready page

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup, pascalscript

I created a code which plays a slideshow or plays a background video when installing my program using Inno Setup.
But I want to add a checkbox to the Background Option selection wizard page (`CurPageID=wpReady`) that can disable the background video/slideshow from playing.

When the Checkbox I prefer to add is checked, I want it to stop playing background slideshow or video and only to show the installing progress page (`CurPageID=wpInstalling`).

I wrote this but the compiler keeps saying

> Line 1053, Column 3, Identifier Expected

The script I wrote:

```pascal
var
NoBackgroundCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;

procedure NoBackgroundCheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if NoBackgroundCheckBox.Checked then
  begin
    with WizardForm do
  begin
    FWAdd:=False
  end else begin
    with WizardForm do
  begin
    FWAdd:=True
    end;
  end;

with NoBackgroundCheckBox do
  begin
    Name := 'NoBackgroundCheckBox';
    Parent := WizardForm;
    Left := ScaleX(560);
    Top := ScaleY(115);
    Width := ScaleX(90);
    Height := ScaleY(14);
    Alignment := taLeftJustify;
    Caption := 'No Background Option';
    OnClick := @NoBackgroundCheckBoxClick;
  end;
  NoBackgroundCheckBox.TabOrder := 3;
end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create the checkbox in the [`InitializeWizard`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard). And test its state in the [`NextButtonClick(wpReady)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick), to decide if to start the playback or not. Alternatively you can also use [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged).

```pascal
var
  NoBackgroundCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { shrink the "Ready" memo to make room for the checkbox }
  WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Height := WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Height - ScaleY(24);

  { create the checkbox }
  NoBackgroundCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NoBackgroundCheckBox do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Parent;
    Left := WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Left;
    Top := WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Top + WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Height + ScaleY(8);
    Height := ScaleY(Height);
    Width := WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Width;
    Caption := 'No Background Option';
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  { Next button was just clicked on the "Ready" page }
  if CurPageID = wpReady then
  begin
    { is the checkbox checked? }
    if NoBackgroundCheckBox.Checked then
    begin
      Log('NoBackgroundCheckBox is checked, won''t play anything');
    end
      else
    begin
      { the checkbox is not checked, here call your function to start the playback }
      Log('NoBackgroundCheckBox is not checked, will play');
    end;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

[image]